# Can the Entity Framework (v4) run on anything other than SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

I'm evaluating a few ORM's for a new project. Can the Entity Framework (v4) run on anything other than SQL Server?  (i.e. MySQL?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short answer: `yes` [Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

Comment: Btw. this should be comment or reason for close as a duplicate because reposting answers (not yours) is not very welcome on SO.

Comment: I agree, almost at "cast close" ability myself, however the question did not specifically asked for EF4 and MySQL, more general case, so it is a little stretch to be closed for duplicate

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it can<del>, but there are not out of the box extensions to allow it to build the templates for code generation</del>.

[Here is another SO question that relates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344449/why-doesnt-entity-framework-support-odbc)

[This question directly relates to EF and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

[And a third that looks like it has implementation steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283820/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-4-and-the-code-first-development-ctp)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have [list of available providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx) for other database servers.