# Keyword not supported exception when attempting to use a connection string that points to a ODBC DSN

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, dsn

I created an ODBC DSN for my Asp.Net MVC application's database access.  One of the main reasons is it makes it easy to keep database credentials (such as server address, port, username, and password) out of source control without hindering my publishing abilities.

So I changed my connection to be `DSN=MyDSN`.

Unfortunately, when I run my Entity Framework queries I get `Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'dsn'.`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what provider did you use?

Comment: I'm using `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use ODBC DSN your connection string must use `System.Data.Odbc` native provider instead of managed SQL client.

Edit:

So now from theory to practice. It doesn't work because of internal EF implementation. EF internally calls some method which tries to get `DbProviderFactory` from the created connection. The problem is that this property is defined in `DbConnection` and it returns `null`. Only `SqlConnection` overrides property and returns correct factory. So EF doesn't work with default ODBC provider and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344449/why-doesnt-entity-framework-support-odbc) is very clearly described why.

Comment: Changing my provider name to `providerName="System.Data.Odbc"`  gives me `System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.`

Comment: `<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyJobLeadsDbContext"
         connectionString="DSN=MyLeadsDSN"
         providerName="System.Data.Odbc"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Go back to SqlClient. It will not work with Odbc because EF is not able to generate SQL for Odbc driver.

Comment: Any idea how to do a DSN with SqlClient, that just brings me back to the original error.

Comment: No idea. As I understand it ODBC is not supported by EF at all. If you want to use ODBC, don't use entity framework. If you want to use EF don't use ODBC. Especially if the only reason why you moved to ODBC is keeping connection details outside of your configuration file.