# Using ODBC for Entity Framework connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, odbc

Is there any way we can use ODBC / DSN for Entity Framework? I am using SQL Server DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Entity Framework support ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344449/why-doesnt-entity-framework-support-odbc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read [Why doesn't Entity Framework support ODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344449/why-doesnt-entity-framework-support-odbc)