# Entity Framework and ODBC

Tags: entity-framework, odbc

I have been working with Entity Framework with Microsoft SQL Server (via `SqlClient`) and recently required to connect to an external database via ODBC connection.

Here are my questions:

1. Is EF on ODBC doable?
2. IF yes, how? or If No, what other option if OBDC is a must.
3. Any sample EF on OBDC project for reference?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344449/why-doesnt-entity-framework-support-odbc