# Is it possible to wrap entity framework to odbc?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, odbc

HI I have this MVC4 internet application that have to access to the postgres server. I'm lack of budget so cannot afford commercial ado.net driver for postgres server. I had a look on npgsql but unfortunately it does not support entity framework 5. So I was wondering is that possible to wrap ado.net connection string as ODBC? If it's possible? does it also possible to use entity framework with that? please give me some advice. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't

You can get a detailed explanation there [Why doesn't EntityFramework support ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344449/why-doesnt-entity-framework-support-odbc)

Under a 100$ you can get some nice commercial ADO.Net drivers. Personally I've used dotConnect (For SQLite) but probably that their [ProgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) package must be as good. You should give it a look. Also they have a 200$ license that can do [ODBC](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/universal/).